# step to know software engineering terms

Tags: design-patterns

I find myself difficult to remembering the definitions of software engineering terms such as domain layer, entity object, busines logic and etc.

I mean when I read a definition of something let say the definition of "business logic" I find many other terms related to it in the definition that I don't know the meaning that make me to google it again and so on and it makes me confuse even more. it seems it is happening because I jump reading something "high level" and skip the basic.

so what I am asking is i would like to know the basics, I mean the orders which terms should i read first. should I read "business logic" first before "entity object" or ... and so on?

FYI i already know OOP concepts.

Comment: When you look something up, do so with the narrow goal of understanding whatever it is you're reading. If you start looking up more and more, you'll never finish.

Comment: Do not read on several resources at the same time. Pick on trusted resource and study and summarize it. Once you understand those notions from one single trusted resource, you will find other resources are repeating the same ideas in different manners because each one has his own way of thinking and explaining.

Comment: can you guys suggest me source book/site to learn this from very beginning?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard because you have no reference yet. You may be able to memorize the terms given enough effort but they probably won't mean anything to you. You need some real world examples to map them to. Once you recognize the concepts in a real piece of software and experienced the problems they address it will be much easier.

So instead of trying to memorize definitions, try to find example code for each term that appears hard to grasp and make sure you get it before moving on to the next.